# Convergence of the product $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)$

Tags: products

I have to prove the convergence of this product:

$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)$

Comment: Do you have a question about that?  What have you tried, where are you stuck?  What do you know about convergence of infinite products?

Comment: **Hint.**  Check whether the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty\,\frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges or diverges.

Comment: I have to find a especific value on wich this product converges, what i have done is just give to it numbres and I found like this way:

Comment: $ (1+\frac{2}{4})(1+\frac{2}{9})(1+\frac{3}{32})(1+\frac{24}{625})(1+\frac{5}{324})...$ and I have notticed that when ''n '' is large the fraccion became small. And the product is around $2.11$ but I have no idea of how to find the exact value

Comment: Have you heard of [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?